# Overriding or Listener

Tags: java, constructor, listener

- Assuming I have a parent class implementing a certain method, e.g. `addElement(Element e)`.
- Additionally the class provides the possibility to add a listener whenever an element is added, e.g. `addElementAddListener(ElementAddListener listener)`.

---

If I subclass this class and need to execute additional functionality if an element is added, are there recommendations/best practices if it is better to add a **listener in the constructor** or **override the method**?

Are there any benefits/drawbacks for each of the approaches?

Comment: There's a good argument for logic-free constructors (so only use them for initialisation). This seems like a reasonable case to override the method, but I would personally implement this with the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: tbh though, this is just a matter of preference and opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing how and where elements are added, then override is the way to go.

If you are only executing additional functionality **after** an element is added, then a listener is more appropriate.

I would recommend adding a listener in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I see a semantic difference between code in the `addElement`-method of the elements-holder-class (let's call it "Class A") and code in the listeners.

`addElement` is responsible for adding a new element correctly to Class A, while everyone interested in this list can add a listener to get informed about new additions - to do additional stuff.

So I expect all code absolutely necessairy to add an Element correctly to the list of elements in class A to be in the `addElement`-method, while no code in any listener would change anything in the list of elements in Class A, but do additional stuff.

So my answer is: it depends on what the additional functionality is. If it directly has to do with adding elements, it belongs to addElement, if it does nothing to the new element or the list, it could be placed in a listener.